# How to downproject with PCA in R?

Tags: r, pca

How to downproject with PCA in R?

When I use princomp function on my data
it creates as many principal components as
there are dimensions in the original data.
But how can I down-project, let's say if I have
10 dimensional data and I want to downproject to 2 dimensions?

Comment: Short answer: Just ignore the components you aren't interested in. Any more detailed answer will require some code and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean doing PCA and keeping just a few of the components (dimensions) then one way is to use `principal` in package `psych`. (Using the argument `nfactors`)

Comment: so how do I get the first 2 components?

Comment: principal(my_data, nfactors=2)

Comment: but how do I extract the principal components? Is it the pca$scores matrix?

Comment: yes. and it would be good idea to have a look at `?principal`